# English-taught bachelor programs in cartography and GIS science?

Tags: cartography

Is there any English-taught bachelor program in Cartography and GIS science in Belgium, the Netherlands, Austria, Germany, Denmark, Sweden, Finland?

I've done massive homework about that, but haven't succeeded. If you know any course or program like that, please let me know.

As the only international language that I know is English, therefore I can only enroll on English-taught programs. Moreover, programs in USA, UK and Canada are unaffordable to me, so I want to do my study in the above countries.

Comment: I've made a few quick searches in the Swedish database. There were some master's programmes in English, but none at bachelor level that I could find. Maybe you should add Norway to the list?

Comment: Thanks very much Martin, although many Norwegian univeristies are tuition-free, but the cost of living is very high. It'd be better to not study there.

Comment: I know a few friends who studied Environmental Studies in Canada who did an exchange in England and NZ. We have some great GIS courses here. So also look into schools that allow you to do exchagne for a year or two often the cost of tuition is the same rate as your home school.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest obtaining a BSc on a remote basis, there is a good programme in Lund ([LUMA GIS](http://www.nateko.lu.se/education_list.asp?cat=5&lang=2)), Sweden.

Another one is offered by University of Gävle (Sweden), you will get Degree of Bachelor of Arts/Science. The program is 3 years long: [Study Programme in Computer Science and Geographical Information Technology, 180 cr](http://hig.se/Ext/En/University-of-Gavle/Education/Find-education/Programmes/Programsidor/Grundniva/Study-Programme-in-Computer-Science-and-Geographical-Information-Technology-180-cr.html).

You could also search a bit more on "gis bachelor europe", take a look at [this website](http://www.bachelorsportal.eu/search/?q=kw-cartography%7Clv-bachelor), for instance.

Comment: Thanks very much, Alex Tereshenkov. I'm going to ask the university if that program is conducted in English?

Comment: Between those two I'd recommend Lund, based on the reputation of the institution. It's in the top 5 in Sweden and (at least was a few years ago) in top 100 in the world. Gävle, not so much, although I'm sure it wont be low quality there either.

Comment: Most of the courses within this programme (Gävle university) were taught in English at least 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with staff and students from [ITC](http://www.itc.nl/study) am have been impressed with them. I don't know much about the BSc program but I'm fairly sure it's in english.